# How to download a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Go js library files in my ASP.NET applicatioo.
I have written below line of code

```
window.open(location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port + "/Uploads/" + encodeURIComponent(obj.data.text));
```

By this line of code the file get displayed in the new tab of the browser and the file content is displayed in the browser. Now I want that it should get downloaded.

Can anyone tell me how to write a code for making it downloadable instead of displaying content in browser?

Comment: You can use HTML5 attribute `download` as `<a href="file" download>Click to download</a>`. Can I know why do you specifically need it in JS?

Comment: Yes: this can be done from the server side, with the Content-Disposition header.

Comment: It is not possible to use anchor tag in the go js library file. Please suggest alternative.